# Unable to install CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I am trying to install CentOS 5.6 in My VirtualBox but I got this error on boot screen.

`Your CPU Does not support long mode : use a 32 bit Distribution`

My CPU is 64 bit I checked that using `uname -a` command and the output is

`Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 4 20:33:44 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

As per my knowledge I need to enable 32 bit support to my VirtualBox but I don't know from where I can enable that.

If you have any idea regarding this then please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a 64bit centos in your VM, but you only get one cpu introduced, try increase the CPUs to at least 2,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in my VM it seems disable i am unable to increase the CPU. it says you need hardware Virtualization support

Comment: @juned output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` ?

Comment: Can you enable hardware virtualization in your bios?

Comment: @jmort253 i didn't enable hardware virtualization in my system

Comment: @warl0ck here is my output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` [procinfo.txt](http://pastie.org/5175550)

Comment: @juned your cpu doesn't have VT support, I checked that on Intel's website